# Search for value in dictionary?

Tags: python

So say I have a dictionary, users, and it has another dictionary named after their uid and contains information like emails, names, etc. Say I want to search for their name, and want to get their uid. Any sane way to do it?

An example of the dictionary structure:

```
users = {1: {"name": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"},
         2: {"name": "Jane Doe", "email": "janedoe@gmail.com"}}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact layout of your dicts?

Comment: For example, could you show a few lines of code that would create a dictionary of the same structure? Is it something like like {1: {"name": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"}, 2: {"name": "Jane Doe", "email": "janedoe@gmail.com"}}

Comment: @DavidRobinson That sample is correct, sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: No problem. I've added that sample to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[uid for uid, attrs in users.items() if attrs['name'] == name_you_are_looking_for]
```

Comment: @NiklasB. `iteritems` is fine, no?

Comment: Yeah, but it's removed in Py3, that's why I tend to use `items` on SO for upwards-compatibility. Same applies for `range` instead of `xrange` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're performing these sorts of queries a lot, simply using this dict format is not meeting your needs.

You should either have one dict per field you want to search on, or consider using a relational solution, like sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

This would be more understandable:

```
def get_uid(users, target):
    for key in users.keys():
        if users[key].get("name") == target:
            return key
```

To use it:

```
>>> print get_uid(users, "Jane Doe")
... 2
```